# N-Back implementation?

Tags: memory, test, working-memory, software

I'm a programmer writing a small n-Back test/game app,and certain things are still ambiguous to me:
1-is there a standard implementation used in research(for example displaying a sequence of pictures or using a 3x3 grid) ?

2-what is the correct way to implement higher n-backs for example tri & quad using a 3x3 grid like this one [image] ,can I use different colors for the other two stimuli or do they have to be completely different (for example A color and an auditory stimulus for dual n-back),and is it okay to use arbitrary large grids or does it have to be 3x3,and if it was okay is there any adjustment that needs to be accompany such change(for example is there a constraint based on the n in n-back that limits the size of the grid?).

3-would A letter and it's color used to create a dual n-back, be considered 2 non interfering stimuli in the same way a a visual stimulus and an auditory one are? and if not is there a resource that defines interfering and non interfering stimuli?

4-when calculating the score should using interfering stimuli be scored differently from non interfering ones?

5-would adding visual effects (for example animating the a list of pictures moving from left to right) instead of displaying them sequentially affect the result in any way, or is it okay?

Comment: previously i played n-Back games i fount this very difficult to me.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This may be too many questions for one posting, you may need to break it into multiple questions to get useful answers.